# If $v_1, v_2, ..., v_n$ are linearly independent and so are $w_1, w_2, ..., w_n$, what can we say about $v_1+w_1, v_2+w_2, ..., v_n+w_n$?

Tags: linear-algebra

As the title says, what can we say about $v_1+w_1, v_2+w_2, ..., v_n+w_n$ if $v_1, v_2, ..., v_n$ and $w_1, w_2, ..., w_n$ are linearly independent vectors of $R^n$?

I've tried approaching this problem by observing that $dimV=dimW=n$, where $V=[v_1, v_2, ..., v_n]$ and $W=[w_1, w_2, ..., w_n]$. Then $v_1+w_1, v_2+w_2, ..., v_n+w_n$ are linearly independent if and only if $dim(V+W)=n$. It follows that $dim(V \cap W)=n$, but then I get stuck.

Comment: You can't say anything about it. Suppose $w_i=-v_i$...

Comment: Re prev comment - versus $w_i = v_i.$

Answer (score 3):

Hint.

If $v_k$ are LI then they form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ and then

$$
w_k = \sum_j a_j^k w_j
$$

or

$$
W = A V
$$

Now $V+W = (A+I_n)V$ so if $A+I_n$ is rank $n$ then $V+W$ are a LI set. Note that it is well possible that  $\text{rank}(A+I_n)< n$ As an example take $A = -I_n$

Comment: This is a brilliant answer and exactly what I was looking for!